# Kullback-Leibler distance between 2 samples

Tags: r, variables, distance

I am working with data that belong to 2 groups, A and B. I am trying to find the variable that shows the biggest difference between the 2 populations and I thought the Kullback-Leibler distance would be a good measure for that. Here's a sample that represent my data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 4L), VarA = c(0.56, 0.43, 0.25, 0.12, 0.78, 0.55, 0.35, 0.36, 
0.3, 0.41, 0.43, 0.5), VarT = c(10L, 11L, 15L, 12L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L), Var3 = c(152L, 187L, 149L, 132L, 132L, 178L, 
240L, 205L, 137L, 125L, 124L, 56L), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Var1", 
"VarA", "VarT", "Var3", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

df2 <- structure(list(Var1 = c(5L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L
), VarA = c(0.24, 0.76, 0.43, 0, 0.52, 0.63, 0.46, 0.64, 0.55, 
0.78), VarT = c(10L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 7L), 
    Var3 = c(205L, 120L, 531L, 203L, 215L, 224L, 211L, 212L, 
    134L, 222L), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "B", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Var1", 
"VarA", "VarT", "Var3", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I am thinking of applying the Kullback-Leibler distance test in a for loop for similar columns to see the variable that shows the largest distance between the same variable in the 2 groups.

To start with, I have tried to run this command from the `FNN` package

```
require(FNN)
X <- df1[,2]
Y <- df2[,2]
KLx.dist(X, Y, k = 5)
[1]        NaN       -Inf -0.1928958  0.0312911  0.1972085
```

The result is quite funny, none of these distances are even close to each other! My question here would be: am I applying the test correctly? if yes, why do the distances show that huge difference?

Note: If any other tests can do the job, I am happy to try them.

Many thanks,

Comment: You could use one of the many tests to compare distributions: Kolmogorov–Smirnov (`ks.test`), Cramer-von-Mises, etc.

Comment: I will read about them, I hope they fit my data. Thank you @VincentZoonekynd

Comment: how can i use scipy to get the generator of a probability distribution with min KL divergence in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have enough data to accurately compute KL-divergence using nearest neighbors.  Even for large datasets, this particular distance measure jumps around when the number of nearest neighbors is small.  For example:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-rnorm(50000)
y<-rnorm(50000)+0.1
plot(KLx.dist(x,y,100))
```

[image]

You have 12 datapoints, so even choosing 6 nearest neighbors would be half the dataset.  Have you considered simply using a T-test, which can work with small samples?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually use a dataset that has around 5000 datapoints in each variable, but I was using this `dput()` to show the case. The dataset I have has no NA values, yet gives me `NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN`. I am still wondering why!

Comment: You might have a lot of repeated datapoints, which would mean that in some cases your nearest neighbors will all be the same point.  That could explain why you are getting the NaNs.  This methodology for estimating KL divergence is designed for continuous distributions, with the nearest neighbors being used to estimate a density function.  If you have repeated datapoints, it's probably not well suited for your problem.  If you still really want to use it, try increasing the number of nearest neighbors and see if the estimates converge after a while.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I do have a lot of repeated variables. Do you think other distance tests can come over this problem, such as the ones @vincent suggested? It is my first time trying a distance function (you can see I have absolutely no experience with them). Cheers

Comment: Without knowing more about your data, it's hard to recommend a good statistical test for comparing the empirical distributions.  I would suggest `t.test` and `ks.test`.  Also, this question is probably better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/, since it is about statistics and not programming.

Comment: I will have to read more about the tests to decide the best one. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi mrip, how can i use t.test to measure distance between pdf? how will i store the probabilities and how will i measure the distance?