# R: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: r

I am working with R. I am trying to follow the code from a previous stackoverflow post over here: [Kullback-Leibler distance between 2 samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179210/kullback-leibler-distance-between-2-samples)

In particular, I am trying to determine the "distance" between two datasets:

```
#load library
library(FNN)
library(dplyr)

#create two data sets
df = iris
data1 = sample_n(df, 20)
data2 = sample_n(df, 20)

#plot KL divergence
plot(KLx.dist(data1,data2))
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Does anyone know why this error is being produced?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because the Species column is non-numeric ?

Comment: thank you! this solved the problem! would you like to post this an answer? or would you like me to do it (so that future readers can figure it out). please let me know - and thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `KLx.dist` documentation, this funciton requires data matrix as input. In the `iris` dataset, we then need to remove the `Species` column which is a `factor` variable. Removing the `Species` column before sampling would solve the problem :

```
data(iris)

library(FNN)
library(dplyr)

#create two data sets
df = iris[,1:4]
data1 = sample_n(df, 20)
data2 = sample_n(df, 20)

#plot KL divergence
plot(KLx.dist(data1,data2))
```

Comment: just a question: have you used the KL divergence before in your work?